# About interrupts?

Tags: c, events

I am coding a basic traffic light control  which will be displayed on the monitor.

In that i need an external interrupt (event ) to happen and change the state of the current traffic light. I am trying to do it without any board or external peripheral.

Now I think i have the following choices . tell me which is the best.

1. One interrupt function to be installed on the system which will give interrupt regularly? (But i dont know how to install that ...any body please help me on that)

2. A C program running on a 2nd PC or hyperterminal which will regularly send some different values with delay to my PC serial port on which the traffic light program is running which will regularly check that value and for one set of data it will change to one state and for another set of data another state. So here the two programs will be running simultaneously on their own system.

3.Or else  shall i go for an external interrupt generator?

In the above methods which is the best way to do it. or else is there any other altrnative which is simpler and do not include external hardware.If any of the above solutions are not correct then please ignore them..
My environment is turbo C on windows.(answers on gcc are also invited bcos i have TRITON IDE with gcc installed on windows for ARM7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just make a multithreaded application and have some treads act like interrupts when thay awake.

Thread one:
Traffic controle
Thread two:
Simulate traffic approching from east and requesting a change in ligthing, and randomly sleeping from 1 to 60 seconds before awakening again.
Thread X use imagination.

In gcc this could be done easy if you have the pthread lib for one example.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is the simplest, you just create a timer that will interrupt your program at regular intervals. You say you are programming in C but specify no platform, timers are platform dependent.

In Unixland, timers send signals to process upon completion. Specifically, a timer implementation for Linux is [setitimer](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer).

You then have to catch and handle the [signals](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) sent by the timer.

In the Win32 API you can use [timers](http://windows-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/using_the_win32_timer_api) as well, but the concept is somewhat different.

Answer (score 0):

Get hold of a copy of **Microsoft® Win32® Programmer's Reference** Help File: ***Win32.hlp***

Seek **SetTimer** and related functions.
This function registers on windows that you want a function to be called after a specific interval (from the moment you're calling setTimer it).
My suggestion is that on that function you:
- kill this timer and set another one just like it (i.e., same interval, same function);
- increment a counter;
- test the counter against constants;

I.e. Counter=10, change to yellow, =20, to green, =30 to red and reset counter.

If the idea is to have the traffic light react to something else, substitute the counter logic by that "something else".

The main() of your program is just your timer initialization and a while(1). The rest is done by the timer-called function.